# Does profunda also mean philosophically deep?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I understand that *profunda* translates to "deep", as in "deep water".  *La rivero estas profunda.*

But in English we often use the word *deep* to mean philosophically deep, or profound, as in  *profound wisdom* or *profound thoughts*.

Does the Esperanto *profunda* also mean philosophically deep/profound?  If not, how do I say something is *deep* (meaning profound)?

Somebody help me suss out the differences between *profunda*/*deep*/*profound* here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Profunda* is also used metaphorically:

http://vortaro.net/#profunda

"5 Metafore granda, forta: profunda dormo, doloro, deziro, mizero, aĝo; li mortis profundaĝa; profunde saĝa plano."

"Metaphorically large, strong: profound sleep, pain, desire, misery, age; he died profoundly aged; a profoundly wise plan."

Answer (score 4):

J.C. Wells gives "deep, profound" as the translation for *profunda*, so I would assume that there is no difference in meaning.

I would assume that 'depth' is a common metaphor when it comes to intellectual ideas, even across languages, so it makes sense to have the same link in Esperanto.

Answer (score 4):

Laŭ [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#profunda), oni povas uzi *profunda* en tiu senco:

> **4** (f) Atinganta la fundon de la aferoj; penetranta ĝis la kerno: *profunda penso, prudento, studo, erudicio, medito; profunda spirito, politikulo; ne forgesu la profundan sencon de tiu vorto; saĝo abunda, sed ne profunda<sup>Z</sup>; ili postulas historiojn kun pli profunda enhavo<sup>Z</sup>; profunde scii lingvon.*